Putting Equations from my paper in latex to my Poster made using Microsoft Publisher
my question is easy but I am not being able to figure that out.
I am trying to make a Research Poster using Microsoft Publisher. I have equations in latex format, but I am able to understand how to put them in Poster even after spending a lot of time.
It would be great if someone can guide me.
Edit1
There is a website called as latex2image.joeraut.com. If you give it some latex data, it can convert it into png format. png format is basically background free. But suppose, i have write something like $\nabla^2$ between text, it is somewhat impossible to write with things properly aligned.
Edit2
I think, Edit1 is the best possible way to put equations in a poster made using microsoft publisher. Avoid putting mathematical equation in between text. If need some mathematical symbol, it can be taken from "Symbols".

Write the equations on their own as a PDF (or a single PDF per equation) and import it into Publisher.

If you have a lot of math on your poster material, you could consider using LaTeX to create the poster. Some instructions can be found here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Posters

Thank you for the response @Werner.

Thank you for the response @nplatis. Is the quality of latex posters as good as Microsoft Publisher? Perhaps, making it microsoft is better. It will avoid putting mathematical equations between the text.

please don't edit answers in to the question

Sorry I apolozise. I will not edit the question further @David Carliste

tex math is generally better but microsoft's opentype math editor (since office 2007) is not at all bad and https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-add-equation-to-publisher-2016-document/f4c8ad38-c271-4cca-a3ce-28b63786ad4c suggests you can cut and paste from Word to publisher, you may find that easier, but that makes it mostly off topic here

@mchaudh4 how would you define "poster quality"? I bet that Publisher posters can be fancier! The link I provided has enough examples to judge if LaTeX posters suit you.

I see several choices for your situation:

Screenshot (PrintScreen from keyboard) your Latex output and insert into Publisher. (Possibly PowerPoint for poster would be more convenient.)
Or open Latex PDF in GhostView and covert to PNG at 600dpi.
Or open Latex PDF in Acrobat and make selected screeshots (by screenshot tool - looks like photo camera) at maximum scale.
Or copy latex code, e.g., $\int_a^b f(x) dx$, to MathType. Then copy from MathType (by default like OLE Object) to Publisher/PowerPoint. Or export from MathType to EPS and then in Publisher Place/Import from EPS.
Or make your poster completely in Latex. See documentclass Beamer.

\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.0{beamerposter}

My real life posters I make in MS Word 97 at A4 layout with font size about 6pt. Convert to PDF. Then print upscaled to A0. See, e.g., https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vbP0SBHVT532593aIyo_KPfYQsNAjjQJ

Welcome to tex.sx.
